# Is there any chance to create VM in ManageIQ using rest API?

Tags: rest, api, virtual-machine, virtualization, manageiq

I need to create VM in ManageIQ (http://manageiq.org/) by rest API.

Is there any way to do that?

I was trying to use https://github.com/01000101/python-cloudforms, but with no luck.

I'am new in virtualization topic so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method called prvisioning do the trick: https://github.com/ManageIQ/manageiq_docs/blob/master/api/reference/provision_requests.adoc

thx.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.manageiq.org/docs/reference/latest/api/reference/vms), there's no such action as creating VM with ManageIQ API